# Snell law with two unknowns

Tags: homework-and-exercises, refraction, geometric-optics

I having troubles with a basic geometric optics exercise which says:

The image shows a glass block immersed in water ($n_\text{water}=1,33$). What it’s the refraction index $n_\text{glass}$ of the glass block whether for an incident angle of $45°$ the outcome it’s a total intern reflection in the right side surface?
[image]

$n_\text{glass}=?$

$\theta_i = 45°$

Snell law

$n_\text{water}\sin\theta_i=n_\text{glass}\sin\theta_r$

$1,33\sin{45°}=n_\text{glass}\sin\theta_r$

But I'm confused because I have two unknowns in the formula and I don't know how to use the $\theta_c$ angle

Can someone guide me a bit?

Comment: What else have you tried, surely you have learned what the expression for the critical angle for total internal reflection is.

Comment: I started recently with geometric optics but as far as I know theta_c = arcsen (n2/n1) which can be seen (theta_c) = (sin (90°) n2) / n1. Is that thought correct?

Comment: You have all the information you need. What is the angle of the refracted light just before $\theta = \theta_c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 equations and 3 unknowns:
\begin{align}
n_{\text{water}} \sin\theta_{\text{i}} &= n_{\text{glass}} \sin \theta_{\text{r}} && (1) \\
\theta_{\text{c}} &= \arcsin \left( \frac{n_{\text{water}}}{n_{\text{glass}}} \right) && (2)\\
\theta_{\text{r}} + \theta_{\text{c}} &= \frac{\pi}{2} && (3)
\end{align}

First, replace $\theta_{\text{c}} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta_{\text{r}}$ on $(2)$.

\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta_{\text{r}} &= \arcsin \left( \frac{n_{\text{water}}}{n_{\text{glass}}} \right) \\
\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta_{\text{r}} \right) &= \frac{n_{\text{water}}}{n_{\text{glass}}} \\
\cos \theta_{\text{r}} &=  \frac{n_{\text{water}}}{n_{\text{glass}}} \\
n_{\text{glass}} \cos \theta_{\text{r}} &= n_{\text{water}} && (4)
\end{align}

$\frac{(1)}{(4)}$:

\begin{align}
\tan \theta_{\text{r}} &= \sin \theta_{\text{i}} \\
\theta_{\text{r}} &= \arctan \left( \sin \theta_{\text{i}} \right) && (5)
\end{align}

Replacing in $(1)$:

\begin{align}
n_{\text{water}} \sin\theta_{\text{i}} &= n_{\text{glass}} \sin \left( \arctan \left( \sin \theta_{\text{i}} \right) \right) \\
n_{\text{glass}} &= n_{\text{water}} \frac{\sin\theta_{\text{i}}}{\sin \left( \arctan \left( \sin \theta_{\text{i}} \right) \right)} \\
n_{\text{glass}} &= n_{\text{water}} \sqrt{1+ \sin^2(\theta_{\text{i}})}
\end{align}

Note: It's not enoguht to say that there's total internal reflection on the right side, becuase that happens for infinite values of $\theta > \theta_{\text{c}}$. Your drawing appears to say that that angle is $\textbf{exactly}$ $\theta_{\text{c}}$.